# How to pass enum into a function that uses a switch case?

Tags: c++, function, enums, switch-statement

I have this block of code that declares an enum data type called "motorGroup"

I want to pass a value from this data type into a function that uses a switch case.

When I try this, I get the following error:

error: expected ')' before 'group'

How do I make it so that I can pass the enum into the actuatorPull function and have it be interpreted by the switch-case?

```
enum{TOP, BOTTOM}motorGroup;
long pulses;
int ppi = 0;
int dist = 0;
int speed;

void pulseCount()
{
  pulses++;
  dist = pulses / ppi;
}

void systemInit()
{
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), pulseCount, RISING);
}

void actuatorPush(motorGroup group, int speed)
{
  switch(group)
  {  
    case TOP:
    analogWrite(4, speed);
    analogWrite(5, 0);
    analogWrite(6, speed);
    analogWrite(7, 0);
    break;    

    case BOTTOM:
    analogWrite(8, speed);
    analogWrite(9, 0);
    analogWrite(10, speed);
    analogWrite(11, 0);
    break;
  }    
}

void actuatorPull(motorGroup group, int speed)
{
  switch(group)
  {  
    case TOP:
    analogWrite(4, 0);
    analogWrite(5, speed);
    analogWrite(6, 0);
    analogWrite(7, speed);
    break;    

    case BOTTOM:
    analogWrite(8, 0);
    analogWrite(9, speed);
    analogWrite(10, 0);
    analogWrite(11, speed);
    break;
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To provide `enum`'s typename, the name should come right after `enum` keyword.

```cpp
enum motorGroup { TOP, BOTTOM };
```

Otherwise, you are declaring variable name, not typename.